# Swift UICollectionView Show/Hide Items on Tap

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

Within a UICollectionView, I would like to show/hide more content when an item is tapped.

Currently, I am doing this by designing a larger cell on a Storyboard, with just the UILabel I want to always show at the top. When an item is tapped, the `didSelectItemAt()` and `sizeForItemAt()` calls are coded as:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        selectedIndex = indexPath.item
        
        print("didSelectItemAt: \(selectedIndex)")
        collectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    
    var size = CGSize()
    size.width = collectionView.frame.width
    size.height = 50
    if let index = selectedIndex {
        print("SizeForItemAt item:\(indexPath.item), \(index)")
        if index == indexPath.item {
            size.height = 150
        } else {
            size.height = 50
        }
    }

    return size
}
```

Which has this output (taken from an iPhone Simulator screen capture, converted to GIF). Note, when hiding/reducing the height on the higher item, the blue box animates behind the lower item.

[image]

Is there a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding UILabel as collectionview Section and expandad/collapsed view as row. When user select label , you can change rows height

Declare section number :

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 2
}
```

Declare row count in section:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    if indexPath.section == 0{
        return 1
    }
    else indexPath.section == 1{
        return 1
    }
    
    return 0
}
```

Then fill your section and rows in `cellForRowAt`

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellID", for: indexPath) as! CellViewController
        if indexPath.section == 0{
           cell.yourLabel.text = "bla bla"
           if indexPath.row == 0{
               // You can declare another cell in here
                let blueViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "blueViewCellID", for: indexPath) as! BlueViewController
           }
        }
 }
```

And in `sizeForItemAt` function

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView : UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout : UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAt indexPath : IndexPath) -> CGSize{
     if indexPath.section == 0{
          if indexPath.row == 0{ 
             if firstSectionOpened == true {
               return 50
             }else{ return 0 }
            }
       
     let width = collectionView.frame.width / CGFloat(4)
        return CGSize(width: width, height: width)
      }
          }
```

Then in didSelect

```
    var firstSectionOpened : Bool = false
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     if indexPath.section == 0 {
          if firstSectionOpened == true{
             firstSectionOpened = false
           }
          else{
          firstSectionOpened = true
          }
         self.myCollection.reloadData()
        }
     }
```

Comment: I wasn't intending to use the sections. The only thing I can see is the additional `firstSectionOpened` Bool. My approach was to check the `selectedIndex` variable set to which item was clicked. Perhaps I also need this 2nd Bool var to check if it is opened.